# How to set menu to an AppBarLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, settings, android-tablayout

I'm new to programming, and I want to add a settings menu button.

Like on the picture, my app doesn't show the three dots button.

[image: My Application]

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.vueSatellite:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/White"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

settings.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item android:id="@+id/vueSatellite"
            android:title="@string/item_vue_satellite"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </menu>
```

What is my mistake ?

Or what do I have to add?

Tell me if there is missing information like the file AndroidManifest.xml for example.

Thanks

Comment: need to use setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: Check this documentation https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar#reacting-to-scroll

Comment: @Rajnish Sorry but can you be more precise, like showing the code to replace or show where to add code and which code, please

Comment: You could use a Toolbar instead of TextView in you AppBarLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Activity just add

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks it works but only with the import : `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I have found what i have been looking for
But i achieved it with this code below in kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menu?.add("Home")
    menu?.add("FAQs")
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if(item.title == "Home")
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,item.title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    else if(item.title == "FAQs")
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,item.title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).